# Numbering at ToC page's footer is wrong

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I am writing my thesis which begins with preliminary pages numbered in Roman numerals. These preliminary pages consist of:

(1) Title page (no page numbering at the footer) followed by blank page;
(2) List of Committee Members (no page number at the footer) followed by blank page; 
(3) Copy Right page (no page number) followed by blank page; 
(4) Abstract (the first numbered page at the footer, iii) followed by blank page 
(5) Dedication (numbered iv) followed by blank page; 
(6) Acknowledgement (numbered v) followed by blank page; 
(7) Table of Contents (showing ii and vi, but they should be vi and vii respectively.)

All things work great except that the ToC's page numbering at the footer. It shows that the first page of ToC as ii and the second page as vi. (It should be vi and vii respectively.) I learned from this forum that the `\vfill` and `\vspace` tend to disrupt the numbering. I removed them but the wrong numbering still persist. I would therefore appreciate any help from you for correcting this error. I have good working knowledge of using LaTex but I do not consider myself as an expert.

Here is the packages I used at the beginning of my thesis codes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[margin=2in,left=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centerline{\normalsize \normalfont TABLE OF CONTENTS}}%
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{changepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Begins Codes for TOC 
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftsecdotsep{\cftdot}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecdotsep{\cftdot}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%End of Codes for TOC
```

And on ToC page I manually set the page numbering with these codes:

```
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}\normalfont TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{6}
\cleardoublepage
}
\null\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Please make your code a *full* MWE.

Comment: move the `\setcounter{page}{6}` before `\tableofcontents`?

Comment: `\usepackage{tocbibind}` to get rid off the `\addcontentsline` for the toc itself... To which part of the code does the `}` after `\cleardoublepage` belong?

Comment: @samcarter : It works! It works! You are genius! Thank you and thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My crystal ball said: moving `\setcounter{page}{6}` before `\tableofcontents` could solve the problem.